# Sharepoint hosted app giving 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I am developing **sharepoint hosted app** and i am using rest api by angular.js or jquery.So I dont accept the app list give an error **403 Forbidden**

Rest call looks like

```
$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('SurveyManager')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": angular.element(document.querySelector('#__REQUESTDIGEST')).val()
        }
    });
```

Response is

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an access token to authenticate the request.

Comment: no need to send with ajax sharepoint hosted app.already i sent digestvalue